# How to split a string into an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I've been having this issue for quite a long time so I wanted to ask how to split a string into an array of "Words"?

I've tried strtok and strtok_r but it doesn't seem to work the way I intend it to:

```
    char str[] = "This is a sentence.";

    // Returns first token
    char* token = strtok(str, " ");
    char *tokens[500];
  
    // Keep printing tokens while one of the
    // delimiters present in str[].
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        while (token != NULL) {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(tokens[i], token);
        }
        printf("%s\n", tokens[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
```

This doesn't print out anything, can anyone help?

Comment: It would help to know what "the way I intend it to" is.

Comment: @ScottHunter You have a string e. g. "This is a sentence" and you wanna split it into words "This" "is" "a" "sentence" and put the into an array of strings e. g.: words[0] = "This" words[1] = is words[2] = "a" etc.

Comment: strcpy() does not allocate memory, and your code snippet either. Actually you only need `tokens[i] = token`;

Comment: Can you explain what the `while` loop is meant to accomplish?

Comment: @ScottHunter FIrst you copy the first token int "token". The NULL represents every other token. While there is any other token strtok copies to NULL(Every other token) the tokens(words)

Comment: You should run this with a debugger, to see what it is *really* doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split `str` in tokens and store the tokens in buffer `tokens`, here's how you can do it (please have a look at the comments I added):

```c
char str[] = "This is a sentence.";

// Initialize tokens to NULL
char* tokens[500] = {0};

// Split the string in tokens and count the tokens:
size_t tokenCount = 0;
static size_t const max_token_count = sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]);
for (char* token = strtok(str, " ");
     token != NULL                  &&   tokenCount != max_token_count;
//   ^ Loop until there are tokens  and  ^ buffer not overflown
     token = strtok(NULL, " ")) {

    tokens[tokenCount++] = token;
    //                   ^ No need to allocate memory here, if you
    //                     are going to use tokens before str goes
    //                     out of scope.

}

// You may handle the case when there are more tokens in str that
// couldn't fit into buffer tokens here

for (size_t i = 0; i != tokenCount; ++i)
    puts(tokens[i]);
```

Output

```
This
is
a
sentence.
```

---

Please note that, at the end of the snippet above, `str` will be modified: the spaces will be replaced by character `'\0'`:

```
char str[] = "This is a sentence.";
//                ^  ^ ^
```

So, if you

```c
puts(str);
```

you'll *only* get

```
This
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a possible help if I understand correctly what your needs are.
I use tabs and remove all the calls for strtok.

From this code you will print only the first word, I let you find the way to print all of them :)

```
int main(){
    char str[] = "This is a sentence.";

    // Returns first token
    char tokens[500];
  
    // Keep printing tokens while one of the
    // delimiters present in str[].
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tokens); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' '){
            break;
        }
        tokens[i] = str[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", tokens);

    
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT

full solution:

```
int main(){
    char str[] = "This is a sentence.";
    char tokens[500];
    memset(tokens,'\0', sizeof(tokens));

        for(int i=0, j=0; i< sizeof(tokens); i++)
        {

            if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", tokens);
                //reinit buffer token
                memset(tokens,'\0', sizeof(tokens));
                j=0;            
            }else{
                tokens[j] = str[i];
                j++;
            }
            if (str[i] == 0) {
                break;              //end of string found, exit the loop
            }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
This  
is  
a  
sentence.
```